# I created a new project w/o ARC, but there's not dealloc method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

It's been some time since I created a new project in Xcode.

Today I created a new "tabbed Application" and I noticed that the `firstViewController` and `secondViewController` created by Xcode don't have a `dealloc` method.

Why is that? do I have to create it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `-dealloc` always needs to be implemented by you. It doesn't exist by default regardless of template type.

Answer (score 1):

After writing it yourself a few times, you will have it memorized...

In Xcode 4, <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> brings up a code snippet library.  You can find dealloc and other generated code you may have gotten used to in the past

```
- (void)dealloc {
    //deallocations
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to write it down by yourself

```
 - (void)dealloc {
  //deallocations
  [super dealloc];
   }
```